# differences between screen bounds/size on simulator and iphone 6+

Tags: iphone, height, width, screen

In my app which runs only in portrait mode, until now I used the following code in the root controller's viewDidLoad to check screen size :

```
UIScreen *mainScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
CGRect fullScreenRect = [mainScreen bounds];
_screenWidth = (int)fullScreenRect.size.width;
_screenHeight = (int)fullScreenRect.size.height;
```

It returns, for example 414pt * 736pt on the iPhone6+ simulator.
And 320pt * 568pt on the iPhone 5 simulator. etc...

Then, I use _screenHeight and _screenWidth (which are global variables) to set various interface elements like views, images, and so on.

I absolutely need correct values : 414pt * 736pt on iPhone 6+

Of course my app runs in non-zoomed mode, since I added correct launch images in my bundle.

This works perfectly in iOS8.2 simulator with all possible screen sizes (iphone 4 - 5 - 6 - 6+).

The problem is that I do not own an iPhone 6+ to check on the actual device if something goes wrong... and I have no plans to buy one.

So, my main question is :
How could I be sure that the dimensions returned by the code above will work the same on the actual device (iPhone 6+) and on the iphone 6+ simulator ?

Is there a chance that the actual device may return wrong values with my code ? (360 * 640 and not 414 * 736, as I need)

Other question :
On iPhone 6+, could I continue to use the code above to deal with advanced graphics:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(_screenWidth, _screenHeight), YES, 0.0f)
```

Especially, is the last argument correct ? (0.0f)